# How to change the options for a symfony admin filter

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a table/class called `ImportBundle`. `ImportBundle` has an `active` flag that can be set to 1 or 0.

On one of my admin pages I have a select field showing all the `ImportBundle`s in my database. I would like to only see the active ones.

How do I change this?

Comment: Is your select field part of a model form or filter form? (ignore it, haven't noticed _filter_ in your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your select field is a sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice, then you should set the table_method option.

For example, if your have Model with many-to-many relation to Related:

```
class ModelFormFilter extends BaseModelFormFilter
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->getWidget('related_list')->setOption('table_method', 'getActive');
  }
}

class RelatedTable extends Doctrine_Table
{  
  public function getActive()
  {
    return $this->createQuery('r')
      ->where('r.is_active = ?', true)
      ->execute();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to change the default active value, remove the active field, or alter the base query?

**Set the default**

Add a `getFilterDefaults` method to `ImportBundleGeneratorConfiguration`:

```
public function getFilterDefaults()
{
  return array('active' => true);
}
```

**Remove the field**

Either unset the field from the filter in `ImportBundleFormFilter` or change the `display` option under the `filter` generator.yml heading. If `ImportBundleFormFilter` is used elsewhere, you may need to extend it to unset the field.

**Alter the query**

Set the `table_method` option in generator.yml or on the filter itself. See more instructions [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_2/Doctrine/en/12#chapter_12_sub_table_method).

Comment: I'm actually not trying to set any kind of default filtering criteria or remove any of the filter's fields. I'm just trying to change the *options* shown in one of my fields so we only see `ImportBundle`s where `import_bundle.active = 1`. (There are a ton of inactive import bundles that are cluttering up the select field.)

Comment: Edited to add an answer for that as well.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Could you really spell it out for me? I'm having a hard time understanding what I need to do.